# Launch file from Java

Tags: java, io, launch

I want to launch a file(a document) from a Java program and phase the following requirements:

- Method must be applicabale on Mac, Win and Linux systems
- I am not allowed to use "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C +"filename");
- The file I am launching needs to be either of .doc / .docx / .rtf

The file is created runtime, a result from a report being created. 
Any good practices?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what launch a file means...do you have a constraint concerning the program opening the file ? do you want to launch a particular application with your file opened ? Are you sure that all the machines you're running your program on will have a program supporting .doc files ?

Comment: Launch, in this context, means to open the file with the associated program. 
Yes, I have a guarantee of having a program supporting .doc

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [Java Desktop API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/).

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(yourfilename));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're running 1.6, use the Desktop API per mad-j's advice.  If you're using an older VM (1.5 or earlier) you'll need to write your own platform-specific code to do this.

On the mac,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"open", pathToFile});
```

On windows,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C", pathToFile});
```

You may need to escape the path on windows.