# Why Desktop.Open() doesn't work with MagicISO being installed

Tags: java, awt, desktop, shellexecute

Here's my code

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
  Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

  if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
    try {
      desktop.open(file.getCanonicalFile());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  } else {
    System.out.println("Desktop open action is not supported");
  }
} else {
  System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
}
```

I know that installing MagicISO (got it from [this Java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6546085)) will make this code doesn't work. But why? What does MagicISO specificially do? Can I prevent it to happen or work it around?

Even worse, this code doesn't throw any exception. It just stays silent there. This really really makes me crazy.

Comment: Can't you just uninstall MagicISO?

Comment: PS: Java bugs take decades to be fixed so don't put any hope on finding a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the 2nd answer for [Launch file from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847838/launch-file-from-java):

You can launch the application via the `Runtime` class:

On Mac,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"open", pathToFile});
```

On Windows,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C", pathToFile});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have not heard of this issue before, but you could always add a manual check in the beginning of your code to see if MagicISO has been installed and if so leave a useful message along the lines of "this program cannot be run due to..."

Answer (score 0):

Well if I had to take a guess, MagicISO modifies the registry or something in some way which prevents Java from knowing what program to launch the file with. If you're looking for an alternative solution, see Adel Boutros's answer