# How to open/view file(.doc/.pdf) in Java Swing?

Tags: java, file, blob

How can i open/view .pdf/.doc files that are save in database? I have this class name **FileAttachment**:

```
...
private Object file;
private String fileName;
//getter and setters
```

and on my **Dao** Class i called my longblob datatype:

```
Blob file;
if(rset.getBlob("file")!=null){
    file = rset.getBlob("file");
}else{
    file = null;
}
attachment.setFile(file);
attachment.setFileName(rset.getString("file_name"));
```

My concern now is **How do i open/view this file on my application?**. I tried something like this:

```
private void lblFileContentMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
try {
      File file = new File(attachment.getFile().toString());
      System.out.println("file "+file);
      if(file.exists()){
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+file);
                  p.waitFor();
        }else{
            System.out.println("File is not found ");
        }
 ...
```

However, it does not work.

**Any help is much appreciated**

Comment: Do you want this application to launch this file on your PC having respective software installed? Also, you need to make sure that the filename exists along with the correct extension.

Comment: Yeah, for example when i click the file it will open, if .doc, word will open along its content same with pdf and other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch file from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847838/launch-file-from-java)

Comment: As i read some article, i need to put my file it on temporary folder? How can i put it on my src(default package)?